# Question about autocompletion for node_modules in IDEs

Tags: javascript, node.js, autocomplete, ide, webstorm

Hi I am new to the JavaScript ecosystem and have been programming in Java using JetBrains IntelliJ. I am used to having autocomplete even for external libraries I download. I am now trying to understand why this isn't the case for WebStorm.

I downloaded an external library `@hapi/Joi` and I see in the documentation to call the imported object Joi and use Joi.object to set the schema. However, my WebStorm cannot resolve the "object or function" did I mess up the settings on my IDE?

How do I get autocompletion for node_modules and lookup their specifications inside my IDE for faster development?

[image]

Comment: Normally installing [Typescript library stubs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files) should help, but this doesn't work for scoped packages:( Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40809 for updates.

Answer (score -1):

[VS Code IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode) might be what you are looking for.

Check following example of `@octokit/request` library with Intellicode:
[image]

`VSCode` automatically detected members of `request` library and was able to provide as autosuggestion. Same can be observer in case of objects.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question. However, please see that the OP has explicitly mentioned that he is facing this issue in IDEA Webstorm. Yet, your answer refers to VSCode. Please ensure your answer is relevant to the question being asked, in future.